# How can I add a fade to this tabbed jQuery content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, fadein, fadeout

How can I add a fade between tabbed content? I tried using fadeIn and fadeOut instead of show and hide, but this creates an unwanted result.

http://codepen.io/saganites/pen/oXPjyG

```
var tabControls = jQuery('#product-data-tabs-control li'),
    tabTriggers = tabControls.find('a'),
    tabs        = jQuery('#product-data-tabs .product-data-tab'),
    activeClass = 'active-tab';

jQuery('#product-data-tabs-control li:first, #product-data-tabs .product-data-tab:first').addClass(activeClass);

tabs.each(function(){
  if(!jQuery(this).hasClass(activeClass)){
    jQuery(this).hide();
  }
});

tabTriggers.each(function(){
  var tab       = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')),
      parent    = jQuery(this).parent();
  jQuery(this).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!parent.hasClass(activeClass)){
      tabControls.removeClass(activeClass);
      tabs.hide();
      parent.addClass(activeClass);
      tab.show();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? jQuery UI already has a `.tabs()` method and options that allow animations between tabs.

Comment: Agreed - I started this with a forked CodePen and limited JS knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `".fadeIn('slow')"`, `".fadeOut('slow')"` instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`
Still little confusion? ou can also use `.fadeToggle()` instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`

**Like**

```
tab.fadeToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 24 of your Javascript can be changed using [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to:

```
tab.show().css("opacity", 0).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
```

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJOwbB

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I now understand better how you can chain these things together.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark as answer for others.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to mark as answer, even on my own question :(